# How to set default date in datetimepicker with ngmodel?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created this angular directive that wraps a jQuery plugin datetimepicker.

How can I get the default dates defined in the controller to display as the default date in the controls?

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/ef1o3c95/5

I've tried a number of variations with `ngModel.$viewValue` but can't get the yyyy-mm-dd text to simply display in the control.

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' timepicker ng-model="date1">
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>
        <div>{{date1 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}</div>  
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' timepicker ng-model="date2">
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>
        <div>{{date2 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.date1 = '2015-09-01 00:00';
    $scope.date2 = '2015-09-30 23:59';
})
.directive('timepicker', [

  function() {
    var link;
    link = function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
        console.log(ngModel);
        element = $(element);
        element.datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
            defaultDate: ngModel.$viewValue
        });
        element.on('dp.change', function(event) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(event.date._d);
            });
        });
    };

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: link,
      require: 'ngModel'
    };
  }
])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use `isolated scope` directive here, and expose the `ngModel` directive value to the `timepicker` directive scope as below.

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    date: '=ngModel'
  },
  link: link
};
```

---

```
element.datetimepicker({
   format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
   defaultDate: scope.date
});
```

here each and every directive instance it has unique `scope` and  that scope is sharing the `ngModel` directive value as `scope.date`. and no need of `require` property.

here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/msh722an/1/)

here is the Directive [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and see the `Isolating the Scope of a Directive` section for more info.

here is a good [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope).

---

And note that you can also use the shared scope directive as like your one as below.

```
element.datetimepicker({
   format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
   defaultDate: scope[attr.ngModel]
});
```

here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gg7ef1tf/)